# Why event listener not changing?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var a = document.getElementById("q");
  var b = 1;

  function tri() {
    a.style.width = "100px";
    b++
    if (b == 3) {
      b--
    }
    return b;
  }

  function un() {
    a.style.width = "40px"
    if (b == 2) {
      b--
    }
  };
  if (b == 1) {
    a.addEventListener("click", tri);
  };

  if (b == 2) {
    a.addEventListener("click", un)

  };
};
```

```css
#q {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="q"></div>
```

I don't know why but my code is not working. Is it possible to add two event listeners in one element? If yes, then please explain how. I tried a lot, but it's not working.

Comment: In what way is your code "Not Working"?  Have you used your debugger at all?

Comment: Looks like you'll be stacking event listeners here. You should try unbinding previous events when you add new ones.

Comment: You're adding the event listener when the page is first loaded, so you're just using the initial value of b. You're not changing the event listener when the value of b changes. I started writing an answer, but I don't understand what you're trying to do with this code, so I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: @Barmar On first click Width div have to change 
On second click back to normal 
Sorry for weak english

Comment: @zero298 i was coding on my mobile phone back then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is only adding one listener to the DIV. It's testing the value of `b` when the page is loaded, and adds the `tri` function as a listener. It never performs the `addEventListener` code again when the value of `b` changes.

You can add multiple event listeners to an element, but there's no need to do that in this case. Just write one event listener that checks a variable. To alternate the action, the function simply inverts the value of the variable.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var a = document.getElementById("q");
  var small = true; // Is the DIV small or big?

  function change() {
    if (small) { // If it's small, make it big
      a.style.width = "100px";
    } else { // Otherwise, make it small
      a.style.width = "40px";
    }
    small = !small; // invert the value of the variable
  }

  a.addEventListener("click", change)

};
```

```css
#q {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="q"></div>
```

Comment: Thank You So Much But Can You Please Explain Me That Whole Code Sir I Just Don't Want To Copy And Paste I Want To Learn

Comment: I added some more explanation. What part of it don't you understand? It's very simple code, just testing a variable.

Comment: Can you tell your mobile device not to put Capital Letters At The Beginning Of Every Word?

Answer (score 0):

your program is stuck on the first function. you enter as 1, and you get stuck on three. I debugged your program into a tragic story. I call it lost to 3. click on the square for the tragedy to unfold.

```js
var square = document.getElementById("q");
var b = 0;
function triun() {
  if (b === 0) {
    square.style.width = "100px";
    b=1;
  }
   else if (b === 1) {
    square.style.width = "40px"
  b=0;
  };
}

square.addEventListener("click", triun)
```

```css
#q {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="q"></div>
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var a = document.getElementById("q");
  var b = 1;

  function tri() {
  console.log('I want to be 1 but I am fleeting, forever to be two, click once more for my story'+ b +'unfold')
    a.style.width = "100px";
    b++;
    
    console.log(b,' wowe is me, am I 2 or am I 3. All I know, is I will be a tragedy of the click handler that will always fire before the comming of the un')
    if (b == 3) {
      b--
      console.log('I am lost to enter as 3, never will I ever be that 1, lost in time to that fading binary dream I once was but am now', b);
     
    }
    return b;
  }

  function un() {
  console.log(b)
    a.style.width = "40px"
    if (b == 2) {
      b--
    }
  };
  if (b == 1) {
  console.log('I am that first "if", that very first time you dared to dream, what might have been had "un" been here',b )
    a.addEventListener("click", tri);
  };

  if (b == 2) {
  console.log('I am that poor un, I will never be, because 2 will never visit me ');
    a.addEventListener("click", un)

  };
};
```

```css
#q {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="q"></div>
```